# Можно-ли переадресовать оператор присваивания?

Tags: gradle, groovy

Доброго времени суток. Начал изучать Groovy и возникла следующая задача.

Имеется такой код, предназначенный для хранения мета-данных:

```
class Meta {
    final MetaItem name
    final MetaItem description
    // ...
    // Еще куча полей с типом MetaItem
    // ...

    Meta() {
        name = new MetaItem("name")
        description = new MetaItem("description")
    }

    void setName(String name) {
        this.name.value = name
    }

    String getName() {
        return this.name.value
    }

    void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description.value = description
    }

    String getDescription() {
        return this.description.value
    }

    // ...
    // Еще куча методов. По два на каждое поле
    // ...
}

class MetaItem {
    private final def id
    def value

    MetaItem(String id) {
        this.id = id
    }
}

// Проверка
def meta = new Meta()

assert meta.name == null
assert meta.description == null

meta.with {
    name = "Name"
    description = "Desc"
}

assert meta.name == "Name"
assert meta.description == "Desc"

print "Success!"
```

Как видно из кода, он сильно увеличивается в объемах при добавлении новых полей, т.к. на каждое поле надо добавлять по два метода. Можно ли это как-то оптимизировать? Каким-то образом переадресовать присваивание. Смотрел в сторону Delegate, но понял, что это не то.

P.S. Вариант с дописыванием `.value`, к сожалению мне не подходит, потому что это всё находится в расширении плагина для Gradle

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего будет реализовать AST трансформацию, которая будет генерить все эти `getName()` `setName()` при обнаружении поля типа MetaItem с названием `name`.